# How in PostgreSQL 12 update on coflict data which can have one column null or not null avoiding that a new row is created

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cannot understand how to update data on conflict when I have a situation having a column null or not null. This actually creates a new row instead of merging into one or I have the error that constraints do not match in the on-conflict options.

The query has to update data when I have the column `site_id === NULL` or `NOT NULL`.

I tried 2 queries which should be in one but having one I get multiple inserted rows instead of one merged.

This is what I tried

1. I added the unique indexes

```
ALTER TABLE candidates DROP CONSTRAINT candidates_day_study_id_site_id_status_unique;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX candidates_4col_uni_idx ON candidates ("day", study_id, site_id, status)
WHERE site_id IS NOT NULL OR site_id IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX candidates_3col_uni_idx ON candidates ("day", study_id, status)
WHERE
    site_id IS NULL;
```

Then my queries

```
INSERT INTO candidates ("day", study_id, site_id, status, total, CURRENT)
        VALUES('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'ABC', NULL, 'INCOMPLETE', 4, 4) ON CONFLICT ("day", study_id, site_id, status)
    WHERE
        site_id IS NOT NULL
        OR site_id IS NULL DO
        UPDATE
        SET
            total = EXCLUDED.total,
            CURRENT = EXCLUDED.current;

INSERT INTO candidates ("day", study_id, status, total, current)
        VALUES('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'ABCDE', 'INCOMPLETE', 5, 5) ON CONFLICT ("day", study_id, status)
        where site_id is null do 
        UPDATE
        SET
            total = EXCLUDED.total,
            current = EXCLUDED.current;
```

I spent hours finding a solution with my indexes but or I end with the error or I end with the multiple rows instead of been updated

Comment: Some sample data for the expected behavior in each match/not match/null scenario would be helpful. From the description I don't understand what scenario you'd want data to be inserted rather than updated. If it's always going to update rather than insert maybe just do the normal UPDATE-SET-FROM-WHERE pattern. Other than that a MERGE could give you more control over the conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately as of v14 Postgres does not support `merge`. But it is cumming in v15.